# Remove line from file, inside a loop reading python

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have a weird problem when reading a file named `ReadingFile`. So what I'm trying to do is read everything that's inside a file named ReadingFile and right after reading a line, remove that line that was read in the `ReadingFile`.

The code:

```
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('Test.log')
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def RemoveOneLine(file, ToDelete):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip('\n') != ToDelete:
                f.write(line)

def Test(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as a_file:
        for line in a_file:
            test_line = line.strip()
            
            logger.info('was [{}]'.format(test_line))
            RemoveOneLine(filename, test_line)

Test('ReadingFile')
```

The ReadingFile content, I will upload on Pastebin because it's too big. https://pastebin.com/9kTwv5Kj  what's this big list? It's a list of accounts, don't worry.. they are public keys.. no harm can be done knowing the keys.

The problem.

After some time I. get truncated data and wrong data, wrong public keys.. too long public keys or too short, or same lenght keys but non existent in ReadingFile..

As you can see in pastebine the first line is `GA25ETO3HJFO4NJLM2PG25WGHWMX35DS4KI7BLY2PA5DTNCDUN2UUSVP` when loop reach line `GAL7MUG4G3MMO24JKESAMWWIAJT4L7TKX74EONZSB7RKDUGAYSWUQ7JG` it starts to get truncated data..

Compared screens, left non changed, right truncated..[image]

What i need is just: `Read file` -> `Read Line` -> `Remove Line that was read` -> `Read again first line` -> `Close program when file is empty`.. maybe i did in wrong way, im pretty new to python.

What's wrong?

Comment: Your testing program is really strange.  While the File is open for reading, you have another function read the file completely and then overwrite it.  Meanwhile `Test` has never closed the file, and what it gets when it tries to read the next line of the file is going to be confusing.    Your testing program should pick one random line of the file and try to delete it.  Or read all the lines, close the file, and then test each line one by one.

Comment: What i need is just: Read file -> Read Line -> Remove Line that was read -> Read again first line -> Close program when file is empty.. maybe i did in wrong way, im pretty new to python

Comment: @SiHa.  That's exactly what his program is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. The code is corrected like this:

1. Adding `close()` *method*, each time **when finished** the file processing.
2. Adding a **missed** `readlines()` *method* in the `Test()` *function*.

[**Code**]

```
import os
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
#You can clear log file eatch time using  mode='w' 
#OR you can use mode='a' to Append it
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('Test.log', mode='w') 
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def RemoveOneLine(file, ToDelete):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close() # we can now close the file after readlines()
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip('\n') != ToDelete:
                f.write(line)
        f.close() # we can close the file now after we have update it
        
def Test(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as a_file:
        lines_a_file = a_file.readlines() #should add readlines() here
        a_file.close() # we can now close the file after readlines()
        for line in lines_a_file:
            test_line = line.strip()
            logger.info('was [{}]'.format(test_line))
            RemoveOneLine(filename, test_line)

Test('ReadingFile')
```